# Batch always sends back to first option

Tags: batch-file

I am using livestreamer to watch streams and a guy on 4chan made a batch file for it.

This one: http://pastebin.com/MyADP1MS

It works, but it had only a few options so I added more until I ran out of numbers and then it occured to me it should have more options so it looks neat and tidy and it doesnt list 30 streams at once. At this point (with 9 options) the batch worked as it should've.

I added more options and now it sends me back to the start. I tried adding a new variable :end at the end which was same as :start and make "0" option use that, but the same thing happened.

Then I tried using Q(and others too) instead of 0 for the back option, then it said Q is currently not usable and jumped to the next option.

This is where I am now: http://pastebin.com/MWsTWR67

I have 0 knowledge on how to do this. To my knowledge my version should work, but it doesnt. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The `if errorlevel n` will be true for any value equal or greater than n. So, you need to check errorlevel from higher values to lower values, but the first test in your code is

`if errorlevel 0 goto start`

After the `choice` command, this condition will always be true. It will be true for any errorlevel value equal or greater to 0

Also, you are checking for the "value" you include in the `choice` command. This is not correct. The `errorlevel` is set by `choice` depending on the selection to the position in the list of arguments. So, your code should look:

```
....
CHOICE /C 1234567890 /M "> Enter your choice:"
IF ERRORLEVEL 10 GOTO start
IF ERRORLEVEL 9  GOTO d2l
IF ERRORLEVEL 8  GOTO gdstudio
IF ERRORLEVEL 7  GOTO starladder
IF ERRORLEVEL 6  GOTO dreamleague
IF ERRORLEVEL 5  GOTO d2cl
IF ERRORLEVEL 4  GOTO dotacinema
IF ERRORLEVEL 3  GOTO mlgtko
IF ERRORLEVEL 2  GOTO bts
IF ERRORLEVEL 1  GOTO jdr
....
```

Comment: I dont quite get it. I did as you said. The list goes from 9 to 0 now, but option 0 still opens option 9 which is the first in the list.

Comment: @user3761241, sorry, maybe i did not explained it well. Please see the edited answer.

Comment: Alright, it works this way. Thank you.

But, it says errorlevel 10. And I only write 0. What if I set it to 11? or 99? I can only write 1234567890. I cant write 26 there because it would go to 2.

Comment: @user3761241, the value of the errorlevel set is the position of the selected option in the list of the possible options in the `choice` command, so `choice /c abcdefghijklmnop` will set errorlevel=1 for option `a` ... errorlevel=16 for option `p`.